# Can't build Cassandra from source code

Tags: java, ant, cassandra

I'm using Mac OS X, my ant, java dependency satisfied the minimum requirement. When I build the source code by

```
ant build
```

I got the error like:

```
 [echo] apache-cassandra: /Users/taiyuanz/git/cassandra-trunk/build.xml
[javac] Compiling 890 source files to /Users/taiyuanz/git/cassandra-trunk/build/classes/main
[javac] Note: Processing compiler hints annotations
[javac] warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.openjdk.jmh.generators.BenchmarkProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
[javac] /Users/taiyuanz/git/cassandra-trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/partitions/AbstractBTreePartition.java:33: error: reference to Row is ambiguous
[javac] public abstract class AbstractBTreePartition implements Partition, Iterable<Row>
[javac]                                                                             ^
[javac]   both interface org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.Row in org.apache.cassandra.db.rows and class org.apache.cassandra.db.Row in org.apache.cassandra.db match
[javac] /Users/taiyuanz/git/cassandra-trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/partitions/PartitionUpdate.java:72: error: reference to Row is ambiguous
[javac]     private BTree.Builder<Row> rowBuilder;
[javac]                           ^
[javac]   both interface org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.Row in org.apache.cassandra.db.rows and class org.apache.cassandra.db.Row in org.apache.cassandra.db match
[javac] /Users/taiyuanz/git/cassandra-trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/partitions/PartitionUpdate.java:164: error: reference to Row is ambiguous
[javac]     public static PartitionUpdate singleRowUpdate(CFMetaData metadata, DecoratedKey key, Row row)
.......
```

All because of the same problem - ambiguity due to the Row class. How can one solve this?

Comment: What is the output of `javac -version`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have source code from pre-3.0 and post-3.0 Cassandra in your source tree. I would run:

```
git clean -xfd
```

To see if that fixes it. Otherwise, delete the repository and start again with a clean clone.